# What precautions should I take if I want to use Tor to hide my traffic from my University?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, anonymity, security, help

I am student at university and use university internet. I am interested in using Tor to prevent my university from seeing what sites I visit and what I am doing on those sites. As I understand it now, if I use tor my university can see that I am using tor but not what sites I visit/what data is on those sites. Is that correct? Also, I have heard that is bad practice to install extensions like adblock on Tor or to login into websites on Tor as it can de anonymize you. However if I just want to hide my traffic from my university this should not be a problem as long as I do not log into any university services correct?

Comment: Unless your university is exceptionally vigilant, using an obfs4 bridge will make your traffic look like nothing, from their point of view.

Comment: You might consider a simple VPN instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes  so far you are correct.

If your only threat model is your university, you may use VPN/ssh tunneling whatever, which may be faster than tor and wont use so much resources for such a simple task.
If your threat model includes more than that, you might need tor.

Answer (score 0):

just 3 steps:

- Run a VM/box **dedicated** to Tor
- Route *all the rest* of the traffic through it - except the Tor node one
- Do not confirm your phone, e.t.c... = keep a digital hygiene up

And it will work for sure